# Cannot register a new user with devise rails 4 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, cancan

I have some problems with Rails & Devise. Somehow I am unable to register a new user locally. I am able to register a user through the console. Currently that is all that works. 
My `routes.rb` looks like this:

```
devise_for :users,:path => '', :path_names => {:sign_in => 'eisodo', 
    :sign_out => 'exodo', :sign_up => 'register'}, 
    :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
```

I've examined similar questions here and followed some suggestions: I've added `resources :users` to my `routes.rb` file as well as the `devise_for:users, "path_prefix"` but I am still unable to get it to work.

My `ability.rb` file looks like this:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.role == "admin"
      can :manage, :all
    elsif user.role == "manager"
      can [:read, :update, :create], [Job, Equipment]
      #can [:read, :update, :create], [Equipment]
    elsif user.role == "employee"
      can [:read, :update, :create], [Equipment, Job]
      cannot [:create], [Job]
      #can [:read, :update], [Equipment]
    end
  end
 end
```

Does anybody have a fix for this issue?

Comment: What's the error stack if any?

Comment: @nicooga CanCan::AccessDenied in JobsController#index & You are not authorized to access this page.

Comment: That's a cancan related error, it seems you haven't defined permissions for the class `Job`. Do you have an ability.rb file or similar?

Comment: Yeah can you post your ability.rb file?

Comment: @nicooga just posted my ability.rb file

Comment: @JoeKennedy just posted it please have a look

Comment: What user role do you create? maybe it's empty.